# Actualizar contenido de un div JQuery

Tags: jquery

Estoy intentando actualizar el contenido de un div en JQuery. El div sólo tiene un número y tengo que actulizar la capa sumando ese número más otro número que hay en un input que le mete el usuario. Es decir, la operación sería el contenido del div más el contenido del input, lo intento hacer pero no se actuliza, sigue con el número que tenía desde el principio siempre y no salta ningún error. 
Pongo el código por si he puesto algo mal sin darme cuenta.

```
$(contenidoDiv).html($(contenidoDiv).html()+$("#cantidadProducto").val());
```

contenidoDiv es una variable con el contenido del div que tengo que actualizar y cantidadProducto es el id del input type number que contiene el número que hay que sumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema podría ser que estés intentando sumar un String (texto) a otro String. Primero debes convertir el texto en número y para ello debes usar **parseInt()**.

```
$('#contenidoDiv').html( //En tu caso $(contenidoDiv).html(
  parseInt($("#contenidoDiv").html()) + parseInt($("#cantidadProducto").val())
);
```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$('#sumar').click(function() {
  $('#contenidoDiv').html(
    parseInt($('#contenidoDiv').html()) + parseInt($('#cantidadProducto').val())
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenidoDiv">10</div>

<input id="cantidadProducto" type="number">

<button type="button" id="sumar">Sumar</button>
```

Comment: Ya está resulto, gracias por la aportación. El problema era por un div que creaba de forma dinámica anteriormente y no cogía bien su id.

Answer (score 0):

estas intentando sumar dos string por lo que deberias convertir los dos valores a enteros utilizando el **parseInt** , además yo te recomendaria almacenar los valores en variables yo lo realizaria de esta forma

```
var divcontenido1=parseInt(divcontenido);
var cantidadProducto=parseInt(document.getElementById('cantidadProducto').value);
var sum=divcontenido1+cantidadProducto;
contenidoDiv=sum;
$('#contenidodiv').attr('value',contenidoDiv);
```

Comment: de hecho en su pregunta el OP indica que `contenidoDiv` es una variable que si esta declarada

Comment: es verdad corrijo entonces  solo deberias sumar a esa variable el contenido de cantidadproducto pero como mencionamos debidamente parsiados

Comment: Ya está resulto, gracias por la aportación. El problema era por un div que creaba de forma dinámica anteriormente y no cogía bien su id.